# Apollo Server context function executed every 2 seconds

Tags: node.js, express, apollo-server

Is it normal that the `context` function of `apollo-server-express` is constantly executed in an interval?

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ event, context, express }) => {
    console.log('context')
  }
})
```

I can see a new log output in the console every 2 seconds or so.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the culprit or better one of the Apollo contributors found it.

According to Trevor from the Apollo team, this is the default behaviour when one is using the **Graphql Playground**, either the web version or the stand-alone app.

I hope that helps someone that discovers the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Apollo Studio and In there It has this setting called 'Auto-Update' Which will request every second to stay in sync with Schema of GraphQL on our server.

[image: Auto Update setting in Apollo Server]

We can simply disable it to stop making requests every second ! but if we were to change the schema then we'll have to refresh manually.

Answer (score 0):

From the [The context argument](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#the-context-argument) docs:

> This function is called with every request, so you can set the context based on the request's details (such as HTTP headers).

It will be executed each time a client request is received, rather than executed in an interval.

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2 thanks for your reply. I have seen this paragraph in the docs too but `context` executes right after `yarn start` without me making any calls to the server. That's why I was confused.

Comment: I am also seeing this happen when I start the Apollo Server. 
And keeps running every second or so...
It does not happen on request only... any additional info?

Comment: i console.log in context.ts file and every 1 second a context  is created with this console.log :D Is it normal?